# FrameLayout Interference with AppBarLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

My Problem with FrameLayout

FrameLayout style Interference with AppBarLayout

I want to be under the AppBarLayout

[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWQlw.jpg)

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try to add this line of code inside your `FrameLayout`: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: fixed thank you, only new problem https://image.ibb.co/jqv5Sv/Screenshot_2017_07_04_02_24_46.png

Comment: That is not whole xml. Update your activity_main.xml with whole xml code

Comment: on genymotion virtual is ok, on my phone is problem

Comment: Probably images are problem because your simulator and phone doesn't have same screen size. Try to change `tabMode` from `fixed` to `scrollable` but without whole xml code I'm just guessing.

Comment: Fixed by removed photos for test, thank you

Comment: You need to adjust images for usage in toolbar. You can do that by using image asset in Android Studio.

Comment: can email you? email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create FrameLayout like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```